# Degeneracy and the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism, operators

How many linearly independent eigenfunctions can be associated with one degenerate eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian operator? (Is there a limit since it contains a 2nd order differential operator?) Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a Hamiltonian in general, or, as your question seems to imply, a Hamiltonian of the form $H = P^2/2m + V(X)$?

Answer (score 2):

If the Hamiltonian is the zero operator, it's the entire Hilbert space.

A free charged particle in a uniform background magnetic field will have Landau levels with infinite degeneracy.

Comment: Why would the Hamiltonian be the zero operator?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? All you asked was if there's a limit to the number of eigenfunctions that can be associated with a given degenerate eigenvalue. There is not, as the clear example of a constant hamiltonian indicates.